# EXC_BREAKPOINT crash when I am trying to create a rematch using game center

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I am getting this crash report from my users. I am not able to reproduce it so only few devices are having this issue.

```
    Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  MY_PROJECT                     0x00089fb8 static MY_PROJECT.GCHelper.rematch (MY_PROJECT.GCHelper.Type)(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional) -> () (GCHelper.swift:156)
    1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x37624a37 objc_object::sidetable_retain() + 82
    2  MY_PROJECT                     0x000403f0 MY_PROJECT.GameScene.ButtonFunction (MY_PROJECT.GameScene)() -> () (GameScene.swift:727)
    3  MY_PROJECT                     0x00052ae0 function signature specialization  of MY_PROJECT.GameScene.touchesEnded (MY_PROJECT.GameScene)(Swift.Set, withEvent : ObjectiveC.UIEvent) -> () (GameScene.swift:355)
    4  MY_PROJECT                     0x0003d7ac @objc MY_PROJECT.GameScene.touchesEnded (MY_PROJECT.GameScene)(Swift.Set, withEvent : ObjectiveC.UIEvent) -> () (GameScene.swift)
    5  SpriteKit                      0x2c668755 -[SKView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 896
    6  UIKit                          0x2c7fc133 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 522
    7  UIKit                          0x2c7f5a41 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 540
    8  UIKit                          0x2c7cbc05 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
    9  UIKit                          0x2ca4231f _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14538
    10 UIKit                          0x2c7ca607 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1350
    11 CoreFoundation                 0x2915722f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    12 CoreFoundation                 0x29156643 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 222
    13 CoreFoundation                 0x29154cc1 __CFRunLoopRun + 768
    14 CoreFoundation                 0x290a09a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
    15 CoreFoundation                 0x290a07b3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
    16 GraphicsServices               0x3085f1a9 GSEventRunModal + 136
    17 UIKit                          0x2c82b695 UIApplicationMain + 1440
    18 MY_PROJECT                     0x00086790 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
    19 libdyld.dylib                  0x37bb2aaf start + 2
```

Below is my rematch function from GCHelper class.

```
class func rematch(match:GKTurnBasedMatch!){
    GCHelper.sharedInstance.rematch(match)
}

func rematch(match:GKTurnBasedMatch!){
    match.rematchWithCompletionHandler({ (mMatch:GKTurnBasedMatch!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if(error != nil){
            println("\(error.description)")
        } else{
            println("rematch")
            for var i = 0; i < mMatch.participants.count; i++ {
                let participants = mMatch.participants as NSArray
                let part = participants.objectAtIndex(i) as! GKTurnBasedParticipant
                println("part \(i) \(part.description)")
                if let playerID = part.playerID {
                    if(part.playerID != GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().playerID){
                        self.opponentName = part.player.displayName
                    }
                } else{
                    self.opponentName = "Opponent"
                }

                //            println("participant name is \(part.playerID.)")
            }
            println("participant name is \(self.opponentName)")

            self.delegate?.enterRematch(match,opponentName: self.opponentName)
        }
    })
}
```

And this is how I call rematch in my GameScene class.

```
GCHelper.rematch(self.currentTurnBasedMatch)
```

I don't even know at which line exactly the crash is happening. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an exception breakpoint, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: I don't know swift, but I had the impression that "let...as" was a cast, not a copy. I could well be wrong on that. But, I do know that GameCenter does not like you retaining pointers to the immutable objects it passes to you. I had all sorts of weird problems, not easily reproduced, when I inadvertently did that with the participants array in obj-c. So, if you're effectively manipulating the participants array from one match object and submitting it to another, I had trouble with that.

Comment: @Thunk I tried it enabling exception breakpoint as well and it didn't stop anywhere on my simulator. 
I am not manipulating the participant array but just using it as it is to create a new game with the same participant as was there in the last match. Do you have any other of doing so?